# Integrable function yields differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an integrable (and measurable) function such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} (1+|x|) f(x) \mathrm{d}x < \infty$. Define $g(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \cos(xy) \mathrm{d}x $. Show that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(y+h)- g(y)}{h}$ exists $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}$, and find a formula for $g'(y)$. Would $g'(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} -xf(x)\cdot \sin(xy) \mathrm{d}x$? I am not sure how to show that limit exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you know dominated convergence theorem. Observe that the difference quotient is given by
\begin{align*}
\frac{g(y+h)-g(y)}{h}=\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\frac{\cos(x(y+h))-\cos(xy)}{h}\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}
By the mean value theorem, there exists $|c(x,y)|<|xh|$ such that the difference quotient equals
$
-x\sin(xy+c).
$
Hence, the integrand is bounded by $|x||f(x)|$, which is integrable. By the dominated convergence theorem, you can bring the $\lim_{h\to 0}$ inside the integral. Then it's just a matter of calculating $\frac{d}{dy}\cos(xy)=-x\sin(xy),$ making $g'(y)=\int_\mathbb{R}-xf(x)\sin(xy)\,\mathrm{d}x.$